# how to get the data using whereHas clauses and relationship?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, wherehas

**user table**

```
id
email
password
```

**membership table**

```
id
user_id
expiry_date
delivery_day_innum(eg:like 7,8 days)
```

**deliverdetailes table**

```
id
user_id
created_at
updated_at
```

**goods table**

```
id
user_id
name
qty
```

**goods table**

```
id
user_id
name
qty
```

**Relationship**

```
user->hasOne(Membership::class)
user->hasMany(Deliverdetailes::class)
user->hasMany(Goods::class)
```

> now, i wan to get the goods whose account is not expired and deliver_day_innum is equals to the 
>   difference between the present day with the latest created_at date

Comment: what u actually want ?? The respective goods of the user with the conditions?

Comment: yes you are right @hitler_jr10

Answer (score 0):

```
$myGoods= Goods::join('user','user.id','goods.user_id')
->join('membership','membership.user_id','=','user.id')
->join('deliverdetailes','deliverdetailes.user_id','=','user.id')
->whereDate('expiry_date','>',Carbon::now())
->whereRaw('DATEDIFF(maxDate, CURDATE())=membership.delivery_day_innum')
->select('goods.*',DB::raw('max(deliverdetailes.created_at) as maxDate'))->get();
```

Comment: would you mind writing using ORM?? i appreciate your work

Comment: it's generally ORM, except for using "raw" twice, it's necessary to use  (DATEDIFF ,max) function from mysql, and for 'join' it's necessary and i don't know other way to do it without join.

Comment: you can use advanced query but the complication would be the same:
https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent#advanced-subqueries

Answer (score 0):

**First problem: Goods for accounts that have not expired:**

Adjust Carbon::now() to match the date format for expiry_date.

```
   $goods = Good::whereHas('user.membership', function($query){
       return $query->where('expiry_date', '<=', Carbon::now());
   })->get();
```

Required in App\Good: relationship with App\User.

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}
```

**Second problem:** please clarify: "deliver_day_innum is equals to the difference between the present day with the latest created_at date".